# Registro de comparación de 1 valor de 2 tablas en una tercera con mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, comparaciones

Estoy utilizando MySQL Workbench y he estado intentando hacer lo siguiente:

Tengo un tabla `Matriz` en la que tengo diferentes cruces de identificadores de 2 tablas adicionales, y necesito registrar las diferencias de un valor dentro de esas 2 tablas adicionales, algo como esto:

```
 TABLA A              TABLA B              TABLA MATRIZ
  ID   VALOR           ID   VALOR              ID   ID_A   ID_B   DIFFERENCIA
 ---  ------          ---  ------          ------  -----  -----  ------------
   1   10456           29   10456           M0001      1     29             0
   2   11598           30   99999           M0002      2     30             1
   3   34678           31   34678           M0003      3     31             0
   4   76519           32   76519           M0004      4     32             0
   5   91731           33   00000           M0005      5     33             1
```

He intentado hacer un `INNER JOIN` de las 3 tablas para después hacer el `UPDATE` en la tabla matriz pero no he sabido estructurar ese `INNER JOIN` o tal vez esa no sea la mejor manera

Si alguien me pudiera guiar en este procedimiento se lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: No se entiende qué es lo que quieres lograr en sí.

Answer (score 2):

Entiendo que lo que buscas es algo así:

```
UPDATE MATRIZ
       SET DIFFERENCIA = CASE WHEN A.VALOR <> B.VALOR THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
       FROM MATRIZ M
       INNER JOIN TABLA_A A
             ON  M.ID_A = A.ID
       INNER JOIN TABLA_B B
             ON  M.ID_B = B.ID
```

Una clásica consulta de actualización, se pivotea sobre `MATRIZ` y se hacen sendos `JOINS` a las dos tablas, por último un `CASE` para poder establecer el valor de `DIFFERENCIA`.